# Some misunderstanding with creating dynamic table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create dynamic table using JavaScript, the table contains two columns first name and family name.

Here is the JavaScropt code:

```
function CreatTable() {

    var tablearea = document.getElementById('ShowDataID');
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var th = document.createElement('th');

    var firstNameTxt = document.createTextNode("First Name");
    th.appendChild(firstNameTxt);
    tr.appendChild(th);
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    var familyNameTxt = document.createTextNode("Family Name");
    th.appendChild(familyNameTxt);
    tr.appendChild(th);
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.cells[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode('John'))
        tr.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode('McDowell'))
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }


    tablearea.appendChild(table);
}
```

And here the the result I get:

[image]

My question is why do I get "McDowell" not under the family name column.Why it is shifted?What I am missing?

Comment: Need to see your css. Probably you have paddings for td's.

Comment: I dont have css file :)

Comment: Post your html for the table please, the html that is rendered from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new `th` for the second time, don't use the already used one

```
function CreatTable() {

    var tablearea = document.getElementById('ShowDataID');
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var th = document.createElement('th');

    var firstNameTxt = document.createTextNode("First Name");
    th.appendChild(firstNameTxt);
    tr.appendChild(th);
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    //********* Look here *****************
    var familyNameTxt = document.createTextNode("Family Name");
    th = document.createElement('th'); //*** Create a new th here. Dont use the old one
    //********* Look here *****************

    th.appendChild(familyNameTxt);
    tr.appendChild(th);
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.cells[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode('John'))
        tr.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode('McDowell'))
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }


    tablearea.appendChild(table);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/judnz5cj/)

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/haziwa/1/edit?js,output)**

```
function CreatTable() {

  var tablearea = document.getElementById('ShowDataID');
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var th = document.createElement('th');

  var firstNameTxt = document.createTextNode("First Name");
  th.appendChild(firstNameTxt);
  tr.appendChild(th);
thead.appendChild(tr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  var familyNameTxt = document.createTextNode("Family Name");
  th = document.createElement('th');
  th.appendChild(familyNameTxt);
  tr.appendChild(th);
  thead.appendChild(tr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    tr.cells[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode('John'));
    tr.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode('McDowell'));
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }


  tablearea.appendChild(table);
}
CreatTable();
```

Comment: Explaination would help me to understand how you rectify

Comment: you missed this line: `th = document.createElement('th');` after `familyNameTxt` ... you had only one th .... that's what was causing your issue

Answer (score 1):

you miss creating new th

```
var familyNameTxt = document.createTextNode("Family Name");
th = document.createElement('th'); // this line missed
th.appendChild(familyNameTxt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create dynamic table row and remove on click delete button row. for this you can use jQuery two method
**.append()** this method used for append html table row, on button click of .add_row_record its get value from text box and append data on table row.

**.remove ()** this method is used for remove dynamic content data, in this example we are used for delete append record. .delete_row_record button remove the record on the basis of selected checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   //add row
    $(".add_row_record").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var mobile = $("#mobile_number").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td>" + mobile + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

    // select record for delete
    $(".delete_row_record").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://www.programmingtip.com/create-dynamic-table-row-and-remove-table-item/)

Comment: This is hard to understand and doesn't seem to solve his problem. Instead you should try to fix HIS code.